# Can I buy magicEden in code?

Tags: magiceden

I want to buy magiceden's NFT without using their API.
Is there any way to achieve it? Because magic eden provides their on-chain program, I think what I have to do is to provide proper instruction data and account Infos.

How do I know M2mx93ekt1fmXSVkTrUL9xVFHkmME8HTUi5Cyc5aF7K 's each function's IDL? And how do I know what account should I provide?

Comment: the easiest way to do it is to use their API. it is very simple but you do need an API key. why do you not wanna use their API?

Comment: If I remember correctly, magicedens on-chain program also requires some keys to sign, which their API does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Harry correctly stated: Magic Eden's onchain program requires a key that is gated by their API to sign, so no you cannot.